# Wordpress. How to display subpages of child pages on mouse hover?

Tags: wordpress

I need to display subpages of child pages on mouse hover as on the image. 
[image: example]

I try this code (without hover effect), but parent pages are also displayed.
http://test06.menchasha.ru/

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
  'child_of' => $post->ID,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order' 
   ); 
  $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
  <ul> 
  <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
   <li>
  <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark"         title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
  <span class="title1"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

How can I realize this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$args = array(
'post_parent' => $postID,
'post_type'   => 'page', 
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => 'publish' 
);

$pages = get_children( $args );
```

Documentation: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: Thank you! I have replaced only this:  $post->ID to $postID. May be you know how to connect this function with mouse hover?

Comment: Mouse hover will need to be handled using css. I would hide the section containing the options. then upon a mouse hover display it.

Comment: If you are using jQuery this can be done easily. see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sLxg1931/